# Почему поток выполнения прерывается на await?

Tags: python, async-await, asyncio

Вот мой код:

```
import asyncio
import logging
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from collections.abc import Awaitable, Callable
from typing import Any, AsyncIterator
from queue import Queue, Empty
from asyncio import Task

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def concrete_progress_callback(process):
    # UI, log or something update
    logger.info(f'Iteration complete with: {process}...')

def concrete_done_callback():
    # result and errors handling
    logger.info('All iterations complete!')

class InvalidOperationStateError(RuntimeError):
    """Raised when an `Operation` enters an invalid state."""
    pass

class StopExcecuteOperation(RuntimeError):
    """Signal the end from `Operation`._execute()."""
    pass

class OperationState(ABC):
    def set_context(self, context: 'Operation') -> None:
        self._context = context
    
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.__class__.__name__
    
    @abstractmethod
    def step_execute(self) -> Awaitable[None]:
        """Process `Operation`."""

    @abstractmethod
    def run(self) -> Awaitable[None]:
        """Starts the `Operation`."""
        pass
       
    @abstractmethod 
    def suspend(self) -> Awaitable[None]:
        """Suspends the `Operation`."""
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def resume(self) -> Awaitable[None]:
        """Resumes the `Operation`."""
        pass
        
    @abstractmethod
    def cancel(self) -> Awaitable[None]:
        """Cancels the `Operation`."""
        pass

class BaseOperationState(OperationState):
    """Implements state methods that raise exceptions."""

    def step_execute(self) -> Awaitable[None]:
        raise InvalidOperationStateError(f'Operation cannot be executed from {self} state.')
        
    def run(self) -> Awaitable[None]:
        raise InvalidOperationStateError(f'Operation cannot be runned from {self} state.')
    
    def suspend(self) -> Awaitable[None]:
        raise InvalidOperationStateError(f'Operation cannot be suspended from {self} state.')
    
    def resume(self) -> Awaitable[None]:
        raise InvalidOperationStateError(f'Operation cannot be resumed from {self} state.')
    
    def cancel(self) -> Awaitable[None]:
        raise InvalidOperationStateError(f'Operation cannot be canceled from {self} state.')


class Idle(BaseOperationState):
    """`Operation` not started."""

    def run(self) -> None:
        self._context._transition_to(Runned())
        logger.debug('Operation is runned.')
        self._context._step_execute()
        self._context._set_target(asyncio.create_task(self._context._execute()))

class Runned(BaseOperationState):
    """`Operation` in progress."""

    async def step_execute(self) -> None:
        try:
            target = await (anext(self._context._async_iterator))
        except StopAsyncIteration:
            self._context._done()
            self._context._transition_to(Done())
            logger.debug('Operation is done.')
        else:
            self._context._step_execute()
            self._context._progress(target)

    async def suspend(self) -> None:
        self._context._transition_to(Suspended())
        logger.debug('Operation is suspended.')
        raise StopExcecuteOperation('Operation was suspended.')
    
    async def cancel(self) -> None:
        self._context._transition_to(Canceled())
        logger.debug('Operation is canceled.')
        self._context._flush()
        raise StopExcecuteOperation('Operation was canceled.')

class Suspended(BaseOperationState):
    """`Operation` is suspends."""
    
    async def resume(self) -> None:
        self._context._transition_to(Runned())
        logger.debug('Operation is resumed.')
        self._context._set_target(asyncio.create_task(self._context._execute()))
    
    async def cancel(self) -> None:
        self._context._transition_to(Canceled())
        logger.debug('Operation is canceled.')
        self._context._flush()
        raise StopExcecuteOperation('Operation was canceled.')

class Canceled(BaseOperationState):
    """`Operation` is canceled.
    
    Terminate state.
    """
    pass

class Done(BaseOperationState):
    """`Operation` is done.
    
    Terminate state.
    """
    pass

class Error(BaseOperationState):
    """`Operation` is invalid state.
    
    Terminate state.
    """
    pass

class Operation():
    def __init__(self,
                async_iterator: AsyncIterator[int],
                progress_callback: Callable[[Any], None],
                done_callback: Callable[[], None]
        ) -> None:
        self._async_iterator = async_iterator
        self._progress = progress_callback
        self._done = done_callback
        self._state = Idle()
        self._state.set_context(self)
        self._execute_queue = Queue(256)
        self._target = None

    def _set_target(self, new_target: Awaitable[None]) -> None:
        self._target = new_target

    def _transition_to(self, new_state: OperationState) -> None:
        """Change current state"""
        old_state = self._state
        try:
            self._state = new_state
            self._state.set_context(self)
        except Exception as err:
            if isinstance(err, InvalidOperationStateError):
                logger.exception(f'Transition of operation {self} from {old_state} state to {new_state} state is invalid.', err)
            self._flush()
            self._state = Error()
            self._state.set_context(self)
            raise
    
    async def _execute(self):
        """Run a consumer to process task queue immediately."""
        while True:
            try:
                task = self._execute_queue.get(block=False)
            except Empty:
                # all tasks complite
                break
            else:
                try:
                    await task()
                except StopExcecuteOperation:
                    break
                finally:
                    self._execute_queue.task_done()

    def _step_execute(self) -> None:
        """Plants the execution step of `Operation`."""

        self._execute_queue.put(self._state.step_execute)
    
    def _flush(self) -> None:
        """Clear task queue immediately."""
        try:
            while True:
                _ = self._execute_queue.get(block=False)
                self._execute_queue.task_done()
        except Empty:
            pass
    
    def run(self) -> None:
        """Starts `Operation` immediately."""
        self._state.run()
        
    def suspend(self) -> None:
        """Plans to suspend `Operation`."""
        self._execute_queue.put(self._state.suspend)

    def resume(self) -> None:
        """Plans to resume `Operation`."""
        self._execute_queue.put(self._state.resume)
        
    def cancel(self) -> None:
        """Plans to cancel `Operation`."""
        self._execute_queue.put(self._state.cancel)
    
    def __await__(self):

        return self._target.__await__() # type: ignore

        # if not isinstance(self._state, Runned):
        #     old_state = self._state
        #     self._state = Error()
        #     self._state.set_context(self)
        #     raise InvalidOperationStateError(f'Operation cannot be awaited from {old_state} state.')

        # if not self._target is None:
        #     return self._target.__await__()
        # else:
        #     raise RuntimeError()

class ConcreteAsyncGenerator:
    def __init__(self, start, stop):
        self.current = start
        self.start = start
        self.stop = stop

    def __aiter__(self) -> AsyncIterator[int]:
        return self

    async def __anext__(self):
        if self.current < self.stop:
            self.current += 1
            #await asyncio.sleep(1)
            return self.current
        else:
            raise StopAsyncIteration


async def main():
    operation = Operation(async_iterator=ConcreteAsyncGenerator(0, 500),
                    progress_callback=concrete_progress_callback,
                    done_callback=concrete_done_callback)
    
    operation.run()
    #await asyncio.sleep(1)
    operation.suspend()
    #await asyncio.sleep(2)
    operation.resume()
    #await asyncio.sleep(1)
    #operation.cancel()

    await operation # type: ignore

    print('done')

asyncio.run(main())
```

1. Почему операция не продолжается после `resume()`?
   Я же ожидаю её на 271 строке.
2. Как можно исправить код?
3. Что вообще можно улучшить в классе `Operation`?

---

Воистину, краткость - сестра таланта. Я помещаю здесь код, основанный на комментарии [@andreymal](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/2742162?noredirect=1)

Если он не оформит код как ответ, я отмечу это в качестве ответа.

```
import asyncio
import logging
from enum import Enum
from typing import Any, Callable, Generator, Generic, Optional, TypeVar
from collections.abc import AsyncGenerator, AsyncIterable

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

T1 = TypeVar("T1")
T2 = TypeVar("T2")

class OperationState(Enum):
    CANCELED = -1
    DONE = 0
    IDLE = 1
    RUNNING = 2
    SUSPENDED = 3

class InvalidOperationStateError(RuntimeError):
    """Raised when an `Operation` enters an invalid state."""
    pass

class Operation(Generic[T1]):
    """Represents an operation that can be started, paused, and cancelled.
    
    Accepts an `async_iterator` asynchronous iterator and calls `progress_callback` on each iteration.
    
    When the iterator is exhausted, `done_callback` is called."""

    def __init__(
        self,
        async_iterator: AsyncIterable[T1],
        *,
        progress_callback: Optional[Callable[[T1], Any]] = None,
        done_callback: Optional[Callable[[], Any]] = None,
    ):
        self._async_iterator = async_iterator
        self._progress_callback = progress_callback
        self._done_callback = done_callback

        self._state = OperationState.IDLE
        self._resume_event = asyncio.Event()
        self._runner_task: Optional[asyncio.Task[None]] = None

    @property
    def state(self) -> OperationState:
        return self._state
   
    def run(self, force=True) -> None:
        """Starts operation

            Parameters:
                    `force` (`bool`):
                        Ignore the command if the state is not valid for it
            
            Raises:
                    `InvalidOperationStateError` (`RuntimeError`):
                        If operation has already been started once and `force` parameter is `False`.
        """
        if self._state == OperationState.IDLE:
            self._runner_task = asyncio.create_task(self._runner())
            self._state = OperationState.RUNNING
            logger.debug("Operation is runned.")
        elif not force:
            raise InvalidOperationStateError("Operation is already started")

    def suspend(self, force=True) -> None:
        """Suspends operation

            Parameters:
                    `force` (`bool`):
                        Ignore the command if the state is not valid for it
            
            Raises:
                    `InvalidOperationStateError` (`RuntimeError`):
                        If `Оperation` has not been started and `force` parameter is `False`.
        """
        if self._state == OperationState.RUNNING:
            self._state = OperationState.SUSPENDED
            self._resume_event.clear()
            logger.debug("Operation is suspended.")
        elif not force:
            raise InvalidOperationStateError("Operation is not running")

    def resume(self, force=True) -> None:
        """Resumes operation

            Parameters:
                    `force` (`bool`):
                        Ignore the command if the state is not valid for it
            
            Raises:
                    `InvalidOperationStateError` (`RuntimeError`):
                        If operation has not been suspended and `force` parameter is `False`.
        """
        if self._state == OperationState.SUSPENDED:
            self._state = OperationState.RUNNING
            self._resume_event.set()
            logger.debug("Operation is resumed.")
        elif not force:
            raise InvalidOperationStateError("Operation is not suspended")

    def cancel(self, force=True) -> None:
        """Cancels operation

            Parameters:
                    `force` (`bool`):
                        Ignore the command if the state is not valid for it
            
            Raises:
                    `InvalidOperationStateError` (`RuntimeError`):
                        If operation was not running or suspended and `force` parameter is `False`.
        """
        if self._state in (OperationState.RUNNING, OperationState.SUSPENDED):
            if self._runner_task is not None:
                self._runner_task.cancel()
            self._state = OperationState.CANCELED
            logger.debug("Operation is canceled.")
        elif not force:
            raise InvalidOperationStateError("Operation is not running")

    async def wait(self, force=True) -> None:
        """Waiting for the operation to finish

            Parameters:
                    `force` (`bool`):
                        Ignore the command if the state is not valid for it
            
            Raises:
                    `InvalidOperationStateError` (`RuntimeError`):
                        If operation has already been started once and `force` parameter is `False`.
        """
        if self._runner_task is not None:
            await asyncio.wait({self._runner_task})
        elif not force:
            raise InvalidOperationStateError("Operation is not started")

    async def _runner(self) -> None:
        async for target in self._async_iterator:
            if self._state == OperationState.SUSPENDED:
                await self._resume_event.wait()
                self._resume_event.clear()
            if self._progress_callback is not None:
                self._progress_callback(target)

        if self._done_callback is not None:
            self._done_callback()
        
        self._state = OperationState.DONE
        logger.debug("Operation is done.")

    def __await__(self) -> Generator[Any, None, None]:
        return self.wait().__await__()
```

---

С этим решением есть проблема. Если подобрать тайминги, оно может выдать такой результат:

```
DEBUG:asyncio:Using selector: EpollSelector
DEBUG:operating:Operation is runned.
INFO:__main__:Iteration complete with: 0...
INFO:__main__:Iteration complete with: 1...
INFO:__main__:Iteration complete with: 2...
INFO:__main__:Iteration complete with: 3...
INFO:__main__:Iteration complete with: 4...
INFO:__main__:Iteration complete with: 5...
INFO:__main__:Iteration complete with: 6...
INFO:__main__:Iteration complete with: 7...
INFO:__main__:Iteration complete with: 8...
INFO:__main__:Iteration complete with: 9...
DEBUG:operating:Operation is suspended.
INFO:__main__:All iterations complete!
DEBUG:operating:Operation is done.
```

Потому что вызов функций не потокобезопасен и вызывает состояние гонки. Поэтому я пока не отмечаю это как ответ. Я использовал очередь в исходном коде (см. первый код в вопросе) чтобы избежать этой проблемы.

Comment: Он ожидается в магическом методе `__await__()`. Его туда помещает метод `Idle.run()`.
Программа завершается, потому что я помещаю в цикл событий `Operation._execute_queue` задачу на возобновление операции. Но эта задача выполняется только когда цикл событий прерван состоянием `Suspended`. А вызвать `resume()` немедленно я не могу, потому что операция может быть ещё в недопустимом состоянии, например в состоянии `Runned`. Я просто не могу сообразить как решить проблему курицы и яйца.

Comment: Метод `resume` добавляет `self._state.resume` в очередь, но ведь операция приостановлена и значит никто не считывает эту очередь, и таким образом `self._state.resume` остаётся висеть в очереди навсегда и не выполняется никогда

Comment: А ещё в той же очереди перед self._state.resume остался висеть Runned.step_execute (но мне лень искать откуда он там берётся)

Comment: @insolor цикл прерывается по "сигналу" исключению `StopExcecuteOperation`

Comment: @andreymal Шаг выполнения добавляется в очередь на каждом вызове шага выполнения. Таким образом, выполнение не прерывается до исчерпания `ConcreteAsyncGenerator`. В очереди всегда находится задача на один шаг выполнения, если операция была уже однажды запущена и никогда не достигала терминального состояния (`Done`, `Canceled`, `Error`).

Comment: @andreyma Вы правильно поняли, почему задача `resume` никогда не вызывается. Пожалуйста, помогите мне понять, как исправить это, оставив синтаксис в функции `main()` прежним.

Comment: Чтобы очередь обрабатывалась, цикл не должен прерываться или останавливаться. Вообще не делайте break, просто проверяйте, что в следующее состояние можно перейти из текущего.

Comment: А вообще лично мне кажется, что это какой-то тотальный оверинжиниринг, который скорее пудрит мозги чем решает какие-то реальные проблемы. Я попробовал заменить сложные классы состояний на банальный Enum — код конечно выглядит «несолидно», но зато похудел на 115 строчек и, главное, работает https://pastebin.com/2qAmUWfJ

Comment: Спасибо, @andreymal. Я как раз собирался переписать на функциональный стиль когда всё заработает. Если вы оформите Ваш код как ответ, я отмечу его.

Comment: «вызов функций не потокобезопасен» — да, вы не ставили такое условие в вопросе и поэтому я даже не пытался реализовать потокобезопасность. Но в любом случае ваша версия тоже не была бы потокобезопасна, даже если бы работала (наличие Queue здесь никак не поможет)

Comment: Комментарии в вашем коде подразумевают, что предполагается взаимодействие с UI-потоком через callback'и — ну так может именно в этих callback'ах и реализовывать потокобезопасность? Обычно UI-фреймфорки предлагают какой-нибудь способ потокобезопасно отправить сообщение в UI-поток — вот его в callback'ах и использовать, а сам класс Operation не переусложнять потокобезопасностью

Comment: А касательно таймингов и «оно может выдать такой результат» — это **правильный** результат. Если операция успела выполниться до момента перехода в состояние SUSPENDED, то уже нет никакого смысла переходить в это состояние и можно сразу переходить в состояние DONE

Comment: @andreymal, "ваша версия тоже не была бы потокобезопасна" Почему же? Ресурсы являются уникальными для каждого инстанса `Opreation`, доступ к ним осуществляется только в порядке очереди (буквально), а в остальном, класс потокобезопасен, если потокобезопасен асинхронный итератор и коллбэки.

Comment: @andreymal, "Если операция успела выполниться" - если она успела выполниться, то она должна быть в состоянии `Done` и тогда выполнение `Suspend` должно поднять `InvalidOperationStateError`. В любом случае, сообщение об успешном выполнении операции не должно отображаться после сообщения `Suspend` или перед `Resume`. Так что **это ошибка**.

Comment: @Aycon операция узнаёт, что она успала выполниться, только тогда, когда event loop передаёт ей управление. Если вы передаёте операции выполнение только после того, как выполнили suspend, операция никак не может уйти в состояние Done раньше. Во-первых, **это правильно** (это фундаментальный принцип асинхронности), а во-вторых, это не имеет никакого отношения к многопоточности и гонкам (в моём коде ровно **один** поток и строго детерминированный порядок выполнения кода)

Comment: Ах да, насчёт фразы «Если вы передаёте операции выполнение...» — если вы **не** хотите передавать операции управление после выполнения suspend, то у вас сделать это не получится, потому что asyncio не предоставляет официального способа приостановить таск (возможно, можно придумать какой-нибудь «неофициальный» способ путём манипуляций с `.__await__()` но это надо думать как всё не сломать — и я не думаю, что это имеет практический смысл)

Comment: @andreymal Я устал спорить. Ваше решение не работает для меня. Я буду ждать ответа от другого участника. Операция может либо сменить состояние на `Suspend`, либо выполнить фрагмент вычислений. Выполнение и того и другого одновременно для меня неприемлемо. Это должны быть атомарные операции. Вывод должен быть адекватным. Когда операция сообщает, что перешла в состояние приостановки выполнения, а после этого сообщает об успешном выполнении - это неадекватное поведение. С точки зрения бизнес-логики.

Comment: @Aycon в таком случае вы должны отказаться от использования asyncio, потому что он фундаментально не подходит для того, что вы пытаетесь сделать. Изобретайте ваш собственный event loop с нужным вам контролем поведения

Comment: @andreymal весьма смелое заявление без аргументов.

Comment: @Aycon я уже аргументировал это выше в комментариях

Comment: @Aycon кстати, меня ещё сильно смущает фраза «фрагмент вычислений» — если вы пытаетесь использовать асинхронную операцию буквально для вычислений (cpu-bound задача), то вы опять используете асинхронность не по назначению. Использование её имеет смысл только если код в основном ожидает событий извне (io-bound задача), а долгие вычисления всё равно нужно запускать в отдельном синхронном потоке. При этом поток всё равно нельзя приостановить в произвольном месте — таким образом **всегда** будет шанс, что поток перейдёт в Done после вызова suspend и перед следующей проверкой факта приостановки

Comment: Возможно, единственное, что можно реально приостановить, — это отдельный процесс (как минимум Linux позволяет отправить процессу сигнал SIGSTOP). Но я всё равно не уверен, не успеет ли процесс уйти в Done до получения сигнала SIGSTOP на многоядерной системе, надо проверять

Comment: @insolor Я опубликовал ответ, который работает, как мне кажется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я учёл замечание @andreymal по поводу активного ожидания в режиме приостановки и переписал код в соответствии с этим замечанием. Теперь исполнение прерывается на ожидание события.

```
"""Support for operations."""

__all__ = (
    'AsyncOperation', 'AsAsyncOperation',
    'Operation', 'AsOperation',
    'OperationState',
)

import asyncio
import threading
import logging
from enum import Enum
from typing import Any, Callable, Generator, Generic, Iterator, Optional, TypeVar, Union
from collections.abc import AsyncIterator

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

T1 = TypeVar("T1")
T2 = TypeVar("T2")
T3 = TypeVar("T3")

class OperationState(Enum):
    CANCELED = -1
    DONE = 0
    IDLE = 1
    RUNNING = 2
    SUSPENDED = 3

class Operation(Generic[T1]):
    """Represents a thread safe operation that can be started, paused, and cancelled.
    
    Accepts an `iterator` and calls `progress_callback` on each iteration.
    
    When the iterator is exhausted, `done_callback` is called."""

    def __init__(
        self,
        iterator: Iterator[T1],
        *,
        progress_callback: Optional[Callable[[T1], Any]] = None,
        done_callback: Optional[Callable[[], Any]] = None,
    ):
        self._iterator = iterator
        self._progress_callback = progress_callback
        self._done_callback = done_callback

        self._state = OperationState.IDLE
        self._lock_condition = threading.Condition()
        self._stop_event = threading.Event()
        self._runner_task: Optional[threading.Thread] = None

    def __del__(self):
        if not self._runner_task is None and self._runner_task.is_alive():
            self._stop_event.set()

    @property
    def state(self) -> OperationState:
        """Get current operation state"""
        
        with self._lock_condition:
            return self._state
   
    def run(self) -> bool:
        """Starts operation
        
        Returns `True` if successful"""
        
        with self._lock_condition:
            if self._state == OperationState.IDLE:
                self._state = OperationState.RUNNING
                logger.debug("Operation is runned.")
                self._runner_task = threading.Thread(target=self._runner)
                self._runner_task.start()
                return True
            else:
                return False

    
    def suspend(self) -> bool:
        """Suspends operation.
        
        Returns `True` if successful."""

        with self._lock_condition:
            if self._state == OperationState.RUNNING:
                self._state = OperationState.SUSPENDED
                logger.debug("Operation is suspended.")
                return True
            else:
                return False

    def resume(self) -> bool:
        """Resumes operation.
        
        Returns `True` if successful."""
        
        with self._lock_condition:
            if self._state == OperationState.SUSPENDED:
                self._state = OperationState.RUNNING
                self._lock_condition.notify()
                logger.debug("Operation is resumed.")
                return True
            else:
                return False

    def cancel(self) -> bool:
        """Cancels operation.
        
        Returns `True` if successful."""
        
        with self._lock_condition:
            if self._state in (OperationState.RUNNING, OperationState.SUSPENDED):
                if self._runner_task is not None and self._runner_task.is_alive():
                    self._stop_event.set()
                else:
                    return False
                return True
            else:
                return False

    def _runner(self) -> None:
        while True:
            with self._lock_condition:
                try:
                    self._lock_condition.wait_for(lambda: self._state == OperationState.RUNNING)
                    if self._stop_event.is_set():
                        self._state = OperationState.CANCELED
                        logger.debug("Operation is canceled.")
                        break
                    target = self._iterator.__next__()
                except StopIteration as terminate:
                    if self._done_callback is not None:
                        self._done_callback()
                    self._state = OperationState.DONE
                    logger.debug("Operation is done.")
                    break
                else:
                    if self._progress_callback is not None:
                        self._progress_callback(target)

    def wait(self) -> bool:
        """Waiting for the operation to finish.
        
        Returns `True` if successful."""

        if self._runner_task is not None:
            self._runner_task.join()
            return True
        else:
            return False
    
    join = wait

class AsyncOperation(Generic[T1]):
    """Represents a asynchronous operation that can be started, paused, and cancelled.
    
    Accepts an `async_iterator` asynchronous iterator and calls `progress_callback` on each iteration.
    
    When the iterator is exhausted, `done_callback` is called."""

    def __init__(
        self,
        async_iterator: AsyncIterator[T1],
        *,
        progress_callback: Optional[Callable[[T1], Any]] = None,
        done_callback: Optional[Callable[[], Any]] = None,
    ):
        self._async_iterator = async_iterator
        self._progress_callback = progress_callback
        self._done_callback = done_callback

        self._state = OperationState.IDLE
        self._async_lock_condition = asyncio.Condition()
        self._runner_task: Optional[asyncio.Task[None]] = None

    def __del__(self):
        if not self._runner_task is None and not self._runner_task.cancelled():
            self._runner_task.cancel()

    @property
    async def state(self) -> OperationState:
        """Get current operation state"""
        
        async with self._async_lock_condition:
            return self._state
   
    async def run(self) -> bool:
        """Starts operation
        
        Returns `True` if successful"""
        
        async with self._async_lock_condition:
            if self._state == OperationState.IDLE:
                self._state = OperationState.RUNNING
                logger.debug("Operation is runned.")
                self._runner_task = asyncio.create_task(self._runner())
                return True
            else:
                return False

    
    async def suspend(self) -> bool:
        """Suspends operation.
        
        Returns `True` if successful."""

        async with self._async_lock_condition:
            if self._state == OperationState.RUNNING:
                self._state = OperationState.SUSPENDED
                logger.debug("Operation is suspended.")
                return True
            else:
                return False

    async def resume(self) -> bool:
        """Resumes operation.
        
        Returns `True` if successful."""
        
        async with self._async_lock_condition:
            if self._state == OperationState.SUSPENDED:
                self._state = OperationState.RUNNING
                self._async_lock_condition.notify()
                logger.debug("Operation is resumed.")
                return True
            else:
                return False

    async def cancel(self) -> bool:
        """Cancels operation.
        
        Returns `True` if successful."""
        
        async with self._async_lock_condition:
            if self._state in (OperationState.RUNNING, OperationState.SUSPENDED):
                if self._runner_task is not None and not self._runner_task.cancelled():
                    self._runner_task.cancel()
                else:
                    return False
                self._state = OperationState.CANCELED
                return True
            else:
                return False

    async def _runner(self) -> None:
        while True:
            async with self._async_lock_condition:
                try:
                    await self._async_lock_condition.wait_for(lambda: self._state == OperationState.RUNNING)
                    target = await self._async_iterator.__anext__()
                except StopAsyncIteration:
                    if self._done_callback is not None:
                        self._done_callback()
                    self._state = OperationState.DONE
                    logger.debug("Operation is done.")
                    break
                else:
                    if self._progress_callback is not None:
                        self._progress_callback(target)

    async def wait(self) -> bool:
        """Waiting for the operation to finish.
        
        Returns `True` if successful."""

        if self._runner_task is not None:
            try:
                await self._runner_task
            except asyncio.CancelledError:
                logger.debug("Operation is canceled.")
                
            return True
        else:
            return False
    
    def __await__(self) -> Generator[Any, None, bool]:
        return self.wait().__await__()

class AsOperation(Generic[T1, T2]):
    """Decorator wrapping an generator into an `Operation`."""

    def __init__(
        self,
        progress_callback: Optional[Callable[[T1], Any]] = None,
        done_callback: Optional[Callable[[], Any]] = None
        ) -> None:
        self._progress_callback = progress_callback
        self.done_callback = done_callback
    
    def __call__(self, iterator: Callable[..., Iterator[T1]]) -> Callable[..., Operation]:
        def GeneratorWrapper(*T2, **T3):
            return Operation(
                iterator=iterator(*T2, **T3),
                progress_callback=self._progress_callback,
                done_callback=self.done_callback)
        return GeneratorWrapper

class AsAsyncOperation(Generic[T1, T2]):
    """Decorator wrapping an asynchronous generator into an `Operation`."""

    def __init__(
        self,
        progress_callback: Optional[Callable[[T1], Any]] = None,
        done_callback: Optional[Callable[[], Any]] = None
        ) -> None:
        self._progress_callback = progress_callback
        self.done_callback = done_callback
    
    def __call__(self, async_iterator: Callable[..., AsyncIterator[T1]]) -> Callable[..., AsyncOperation]:
        def AsyncGeneratorWrapper(*T2, **T3):
            return AsyncOperation(
                async_iterator=async_iterator(*T2, **T3),
                progress_callback=self._progress_callback,
                done_callback=self.done_callback)
        return AsyncGeneratorWrapper
```

Использование:

```
import asyncio
import logging
import time
from collections.abc import AsyncIterator
from typing import Iterator

from operating import AsAsyncOperation, AsOperation

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def concrete_progress_callback(process) -> None:
    # UI, log or something update
    logger.info(f"Iteration complete with: {process}...")


def concrete_done_callback() -> None:
    # result and errors handling
    logger.info("All iterations complete!")


@AsAsyncOperation(progress_callback=concrete_progress_callback, done_callback=concrete_done_callback)
class ConcreteAsyncGenerator:
    def __init__(self, start: int, stop: int):
        self.current = start
        self.start = start
        self.stop = stop

    def __aiter__(self) -> AsyncIterator[int]:
        return self

    async def __anext__(self) -> int:
        if self.current < self.stop:
            self.current += 1
            await asyncio.sleep(0.01)
            return self.current
        raise StopAsyncIteration


@AsOperation(progress_callback=concrete_progress_callback, done_callback=concrete_done_callback)
class ConcreteGenerator:
    def __init__(self, start: int, stop: int):
        self.current = start
        self.start = start
        self.stop = stop

    def __iter__(self) -> Iterator[int]:
        return self

    def __next__(self) -> int:
        if self.current < self.stop:
            self.current += 1
            time.sleep(0.01)
            return self.current
        
        return 42
        raise StopAsyncIteration


@AsAsyncOperation(progress_callback=concrete_progress_callback, done_callback=concrete_done_callback)
async def async_squares(start, stop):
    for i in range(start, stop):
        yield i * i
        await asyncio.sleep(0.01)


@AsOperation(progress_callback=concrete_progress_callback, done_callback=concrete_done_callback)
def squares(start, stop):
    for i in range(start, stop):
        yield i * i
        time.sleep(0.01)
    return 'squares'


async def async_main() -> None:
    sqrt_n = 100
    operations = [async_squares(i*sqrt_n, i*sqrt_n + sqrt_n)
                  for i in range(sqrt_n)]
    for operation in operations:
        await operation.run()
    await asyncio.wait(operations)

    operation = async_squares(0, 100)
    await operation.run()
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    await operation.suspend()
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    await operation.resume()
    await operation

    operation = ConcreteAsyncGenerator(0, 1000)
    await operation.run()
    await asyncio.sleep(4)
    await operation.suspend()
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    await operation.resume()
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    await operation.cancel()
    await operation.wait()


def main() -> None:
    sqrt_n = 100
    operations = [squares(i*sqrt_n, i*sqrt_n + sqrt_n) for i in range(sqrt_n)]
    for operation in operations:
        operation.run()

    for operation in operations:
        operation.wait()

    operation = squares(0, 100)
    operation.run()
    time.sleep(1)
    operation.suspend()
    time.sleep(3)
    operation.resume()
    operation.join()

    operation = ConcreteGenerator(0, 1000)
    operation.run()
    time.sleep(4)
    operation.suspend()
    time.sleep(3)
    operation.resume()
    time.sleep(1)
    operation.cancel()
    operation.wait()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(async_main())
    main()
```

Comment: Ага, у меня код зависает при попытке вызвать suspend. Метод _runner возвращает управление в event loop, прерываясь на ближайшем await (например `target = await anext(self._async_iterator)`), а блокировка при этом остаётся захваченной, затем вызов suspend в каком-нибудь другом таске тоже пытается захватить ту же блокировку и зависает. Из-за этого зависания никто не возвращает управление в event loop, как следствие он не может вернуть управление в метод _runner и блокировка остаётся захваченной навсегда

Comment: @andreymal да, я пытаюсь это решить. Мне кажется, эта проблема - вариация исходной проблемы (см. самый первый код в вопросе)

Comment: Мне кажется, вы бы сильно облегчили себе жизнь, если бы сделали методы suspend/resume/cancel асинхронными. Если ваша бизнес-логика допускает, чтобы методы suspend/resume/cancel могли ненадолго зависнуть до фактического перехода операции в запрошенное состояние (судя по тому, что вы не стесняетесь использовать блокировку, я делаю вывод, что это для вас допустимо), то воткнуть какой-нибудь маленький await было бы намного проще чем возиться с блокировками и очередями (ну правда, очередь тут нафиг не нужна)

Comment: @andreymal, я попробовал, но это не работает. Управляющие функции вызываются до запуска `_runner`

Comment: Ну, в вашей реализации есть такая же проблема: если поставить обе функции подряд без задержек `op.run(); op.suspend()` то точно так же операция перейдёт в состояние suspended до начала работы _runner (по той же самой причине — здесь нет передачи управления в event loop и у него нет возможности запустить _runner до ближайшего await)

Comment: Если вам важно дождаться начала работы _runner, то метод run тоже можно сделать асинхронным ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @andreymal Я исправил пример выше. Это работает у вас?

Comment: Работает, только изначальная проблема никуда не делась: из-за того, что вы убрали блокировку внутри _runner, у операции опять появилась возможность выполнить фрагмент вычислений в состоянии suspended https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fDtr.png

Comment: И кстати вы замаскировали факт выполнения вычислений: из-за того, что у вас _progress_callback вызывается после await _resume_signal, он не будет вызван в состоянии suspended, хотя в это время в переменной target уже лежит готовое вычисление, выполненное в состоянии suspended

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146792/discussion-between-aycon-and-andreymal).

Comment: @andreymal, Я обновил код. Он выглядит рабочим. так ли это? Я освобождаю блокировку в `_runner` только на ожидание сигнала. Теперь все управляющие функции асинхронны.

Comment: если блокировка    метода  суспенд на время шага допустима, то я бы использовал asyncio.Condition

Comment: @eri, спасибо, это превосходная вещь! Как только я разберусь как это работает, я перепишу код с Condition

Comment: @eri, @andreymal, я переписал код с `asyncio.Condition`. Вроде работает. Можно ли ещё как-то улучшить этот ответ?